# Assigning new Java Resultset object to existing one, then closing the original ResultSet object causes the newly created one to be closed?

Tags: java, object, jdbc, resultset

All,

For a class called Analyse and its constructor Analyse which takes a Java JDBC Resultset object as an argument.

```
private Resultset analysisSet

public void Analyse(ResultSet queryResults)
{
    analysisSet = queryResults;
    queryResults.close();
}

public void doSomeStuff()
{
    analysisSet.next() //throws SQL Exception "Closed Resultset : next"
}
```

However if I comment out the "queryResults.close()" statement then it works fine?

Surely after I assign an object to equal another one they become mutually exclusive to one another?

If someone could explain whats happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object assignment in Java is by reference, not by value. In the simple case

```
int [] a = new int[] { 17 };
int [] b = a;

b[0] = 11;
// a[0] is 11 now.
```

Same for the result set. When you just assign it to the new variable, you do not clone it. It is just a different reference the same object.

ResultSet cannot easily be cloned and in general it is not the best practice to keep it opened for a while assigned to the object field. Best would be to copy data to your own data structure and close the ResultSet as soon as possible.

Comment: In C++ I could do a complete assignment like this without it referencing, how do I make a copy>

Comment: You may look into protected clone() method that just copies all fields, very much like C structure assignment does. But it is not considered as a very good method to use.

Comment: Don't copy it, once you're done using it, call first() on it to reset it. This is a weird use case. Why do you need two references to the same ResultSet?

Answer (score 1):

The two references are pointing to the same result set object.

When you close one, you close the other too.
It is better to say that when you call close on one of the references,
this closes the result set object. So the other reference is pointing
to that same (now closed) result set object.

This is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you are dealing with references. I always think of them sort like pointers so in your code when you do `analysisSet = queryResults;` you are not copying the object you are just adding another reference to it. So you have one ResultSet with 2 references to it. If you close this result set (using one of the references) then it is closed when accessed by both.